# How to Unload a TabBar View when New TabBar view is loaded?

Tags: iphone, uitabbar, viewcontroller

I am playing an audio file in a viewcontroller inside an UITabBar using AVAudioPlayer. So when user clicks a different tabbar item the music is not stopped. I tried adding stop method in viewwilldisappear. But it's not responding. How can I stop my audio when user clicks a new tab bar item.
ente

```
AVAudioPlayer *audioPlayer;
```

This is my code in view will disappear

```
[audioPlayer stop];
[sliderTimer invalidate];
audioPlayer = nil;
self.URL = nil;
self.musicTitle = nil;
```

Thanks,
Nikil

Comment: Is that code getting called for sure?

Answer (score 1):

This worked for me.

- (void)viewWillDisappear:(BOOL)animated {
  [self.audioPlayer stop];

}